# How to create Python app , which asks for sudo permissions?

Tags: python, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call a dialog for authentication?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125314/how-do-i-call-a-dialog-for-authentication)

My application needs sudo permissions , so I want that when program starts , it asks for sudo permission , like Software Center does , when something will be installed. I`m using python and GTK+.